# issues with jquery datatable all selected checkboxes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables and when multiple checkboxes are selected & I click the bulk delete button it should show the checkbox values in the console however I'm getting no errors and no output

Here is the code

```
// Listing the ID names to match up with code below 
// Bulk Delete button ID = bulkdel
// Table ID = companylist
// Checkbox class name = checkboxdt

$("#bulkdel").click(function() {
      var oTable = $('#companylist').dataTable();
      var rowcollection =  oTable.$(".checkboxdt:checked", {"page": "all"});
      rowcollection.each(function(index,elem){
          var checkbox_value = $(elem).val();
          console.log(checkbox_value);
      });
});
```

Comment: The first four lines aren't valid JavaScript. `:)`

Comment: I know I put them there so you can confirm my ID / class names

Comment: Ah, I commented them... `:)`

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with jquery DataTable but if you've initialised the datatable somewhere already, do you need the oTable var? would var rowcollection =  oTable.$("#companylist.checkboxdt:checked", {"page": "all"}); not work? I suggest you add some more console.dir() commands in to your code to debug it. See if console.dir(oTable) and console.dir(rowcollection) are what you expect them to be.

Comment: not getting any output still

Comment: You aren't getting output when doing what?

Comment: Ive added both console.dir(oTable) & console.dir(rowcollection) but its not showing any properties of the element

Comment: try just adding something like console.log("TEST"); before the var oTable and seeing if that get's called. If not, it is $("#bulkdel").click(function() not working and the button click is not working. Also make sure your console is set to display all information.

Comment: Yep test is being shown in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179109/discussion-between-petay87-and-chris-yates).

Comment: Anyone else able to shed some light on this as @Petay87 has exhausted all of his solutions